# Splitting varieties of two Galois cohomology symbols

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, motives, galois-cohomology

One characteristic property of the so called norm varieties defined by Rost, is that they split pure symbols of Galois cohomology groups $H^n(k,\mu_p)$, meaning:

For some $\alpha \in H^n(k,\mu_p)$ there is a smooth, projective $X_\alpha$ such that

$X_\alpha$ has a $L$-rational point iff $\alpha = 0$ in $H^n(L,\mu_p)$ for all extensions $L/k$.

We call such a variety a splitting variety for $\alpha$.

Lets assume we have non trivial, pure symbols $\alpha \in H^n(k,\mu_p)$ and $\beta \in H^m(k,\mu_l)$ for different primes $p,l$.

Is there an example of a variety $X$ which is a splitting variety for both symbols $\alpha, \beta$ i.e. is it possible to construct such a thing?

Is it possible when we restrict our definition to field extensions of dimension $p*l$ ?

Edit: There is some deeper meaning to my question. Since the symbols determine norm varieties, which have generalized Rost-motives $R_\alpha$, $R_\beta$ in their motivic decomposition, the motiv of $X$ would contain both of these summands. Further it might be that one obtains splitting equivalence of $R_\alpha$, $R_\beta$ from this i.e. one splits iff the other splits, although at first sight these motives have nothing in common. So the existence of such an $X$ would interest me.

Answer (score 2):

Won't the product variety $X_{\alpha} \times X_{\beta}$ do the trick?

Comment: Hm i am actually interested in the chow motives, but i cut that part down to make my question easier to understand. Does the motivic decomposition of that product variety contain the two generalized Rost-motives of the respective symbols? The purpose of such a double splitting variety is to establish splitting equivalence between two generalized Rost-motives. So i need an (counter) example to understand if constructing such an variety is even possible.

Comment: Maybe I didn't understand what you meant by a splitting variety for both symbols.  I took that to mean a variety $X$ which for $L/k$ has an $L$-rational point iff both cohomology classes become trivial upon restriction to $L$.  If so, $(X_{\alpha} \times X_{\beta})(L) \neq \varnothing \iff X_{\alpha}(L) \neq \varnothing$ and $X_{\beta}(L) \neq \varnothing$.  There's no more to my answer than that.

Comment: Your example is indeed doing for what i actually asked, but as i pointed out i was expecting something more fancier. I think i will edit something towards the end of my post.